# gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file -> problem in extracting jdk-7u55-linux-x64.tar.gz

Tags: java, 14.04, jdk, tar

I have downloaded 'jdk-7u55-linux-x64.tar.gz'

When I execute following command to extract,

```
 sudo tar xvzf jdk-7u55-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

also tried,

```
sudo tar xvf jdk-7u55-linux-x64.tar.gz
sudo tar xf jdk-7u55-linux-x64.tar.gz
sudo tar -xvf jdk-7u55-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

But am getting error at last as,

```
gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Please don't use `sudo` unless necessary. If you are extracting this into a directory you have access to, there's no need for `sudo`.

Anyway, the error you're getting is usually due to an incomplete download. The archive ends before the expected footer of the gzipped file. It will probably work fine if you just download it again.

Comment: can you list me where are sudo required?

Comment: @AJ when you get a "Permission denied" error. You should _only_ use `sudo` for actions that your regular user cannot do because of permissions issues. Do not use it by default since that can cause all sorts of problems down the line.